# Retain only one copy of an activity on the stack when called from non-activity

Tags: android, stack, android-activity, android-intent, notifications

How can I make sure I only retain one copy of an activity on the stack when called from non-activity?

When called from an activity I can just add the FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag to the Intent, but how can I do this from e.g. a widget or a notification?